# How do I obtain a nether reactor core in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I obtain a nether reactor core (as well as other blocks that cannot be obtained/removed)?

Answer (score 3):

The nether reactor core can no longer be crafted or found in creative inventory and can only be obtained through inventory editors currently. [Source here.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Reactor_Core)

Comment: But how do I do that? Is there an Android app I can use???

Comment: @caseylanecalhoun There are a bunch of different _inventory editors for MCPE_ but I can't say which to use since I'm not familiar with them, and advice like that falls into off-topic here because it's asking for recommendations. You can read more about that [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/so-what-actually-is-a-game-rec) and [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: Figured it out, had to fiddle around with an app I got to make it work. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can't obtain them the normal way.
You would have to use an inventory editor.
I'm pretty sure they still work, though.